# Counters for claims

Tags: numbering, environments

I want to redefine the claim environment so that it will be numbered but I'm having a hard time with the counters.

I want the following:

```
\begin{theorem}
thm 1
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  \begin{claim}
  blah 1
  \end{claim}

  \begin{claim}
  blah 2
  \end{claim}
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
thm 2
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  \begin{claim}
  blah 3
  \end{claim}
\end{proof}
```

to produce:

```
Theorem 1: thm 1
Claim 1.1: blah 1
Claim 1.2: blah 2

Theorem 2: thm 2
Claim 2.1: blah 3
```

Comment: First of all it is good practice to provide a full minimal example. Might be nice for example to see now `claim` was defined.

Comment: Isn't that what I did? My question concerns the counters. You can replace `claim` with `proposition`, `example`, etc..

Comment: A MWE should be something that shows how you've already tried to implement the idea.  It'll show the class you're using, the packages you're loading, and the commands and environments you've created.  Of course, it's a **minimal** working example.  So it should reflect only that which is necessary for the question as hand.

Comment: Exactly, it should be something people can copy'n'paste to their favourite editor and try out without having to guess the preamble or add extra stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a MWE that shows how to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newcounter{claimcounter}
\numberwithin{claimcounter}{thm}
\newenvironment{claim}{\stepcounter{claimcounter}{Claim \theclaimcounter:}}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
    Just testing.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
    \begin{claim}
        first
    \end{claim}

    \begin{claim}
        second
    \end{claim}

    \begin{claim}
        third
    \end{claim}
\end{proof}

\begin{thm}
    Just testing.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
    Just testing.
\end{thm}

    \begin{claim}
        first
    \end{claim}

    \begin{claim}
        second
    \end{claim}

    \begin{claim}
        third
    \end{claim}


\end{document}
```

The command `\numberwithin` allows the claims to be counted with respect to the theorem they are most closely associated with.  `\newenvironment` allows you to create the environment for the claim---I haven't done much here other than issue out claim numbers.

[image]

Comment: `\newcounter{claimcounter}[thm]` avoids the need of `\numberwithin`